# How do you combine Range and Individual / Array Columns Selection in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I want to select:

- 2nd column
- from the 3rd column onwards every odd column including the 3rd column also

from a Pandas dataframe. [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) mentions the following:

> - An integer, e.g. 5.
> - A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].
> - A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.
> - A boolean array.
> - A callable function with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)

My requirement seems to be a combination of an integer and range object or an array with a range object, e.g. `.iloc[:, [2, 3::2]]`. What is the best and easiest way achieve the above?

Comment: What about `.iloc[3::2, 2]`

Comment: @ksai Isnt that the third column?

Comment: `from the 3rd row onwards every odd column` - do you mean `from the 3rd __column__ onwards every odd column` ?

Comment: 2nd column + every odd column from the 3rd column onwards including the 3rd column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use [numpy.r_[...]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

Demo:

```
In [126]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10), columns=list(range(1, 11)))

In [127]: df
Out[127]:
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10
0  0.971111  0.209419  0.266902  0.410897  0.702329  0.199330  0.622634  0.391587  0.357186  0.738886
1  0.195173  0.409414  0.543279  0.090533  0.621940  0.096192  0.050050  0.513417  0.384031  0.191914
2  0.973278  0.825286  0.434370  0.012834  0.694801  0.645579  0.261067  0.240224  0.488762  0.665984
3  0.671826  0.184333  0.773337  0.870569  0.325016  0.871609  0.968624  0.103269  0.347466  0.262120
4  0.268309  0.242649  0.098463  0.979625  0.500496  0.965501  0.544177  0.959747  0.411557  0.979344

In [128]: df.iloc[:, np.r_[1, 2:df.shape[1]:2]]
Out[128]:
          2         3         5         7         9
0  0.209419  0.266902  0.702329  0.622634  0.357186
1  0.409414  0.543279  0.621940  0.050050  0.384031
2  0.825286  0.434370  0.694801  0.261067  0.488762
3  0.184333  0.773337  0.325016  0.968624  0.347466
4  0.242649  0.098463  0.500496  0.544177  0.411557
```

Comment: This does not seem to have the 2nd column

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena, i've updated my post - please check